# Can my other Chase credit card points use the 3x multiplier of the CSR card?

Tags: credit-card, points

I have two chase credit cards with over $300 worth of points and will open another Chase card next month, the [Chase Sapphire Reserve (CSR)](https://creditcards.chase.com/rewards-credit-cards/chase-sapphire-reserve). I am wondering if my existing Chase points will get the 3x multiplier from the CSR card when I eventually open that card. It may be that I only get the benefit of the 3x multiplier on points earned through the CSR card but wanted to be sure before redeeming my existing points. If they do get the benefit of the 3 multiplier I will hold on to them. Does anyone know how this rule works for Chase rewards points?

Bonus question: Can I open the [Chase Sapphire Preferred (CSP)](https://creditcards.chase.com/rewards-credit-cards/chase-sapphire-preferred), then product change to the CSR and get the 3x multiplier on the points earned from the CSP?

Comment: To answer the bonus question, I tried to upgrade from CSP to CSR in the middle of a work trip when I knew I would have a considerable amount more travel spend incoming, justifying the fee, and learned that the rule is that CSP->CSR upgrade requires the account to have been open for at least 12 months.  Additional note: although that means you'll have to pay a $95 annual fee on the CSP anniversary before doing the upgrade, that counts toward the CSR annual fee.  But the 12 month rule is quite limiting -- if you already know you want the CSR, apply for it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The travel redemption is 1.5x not 3x and only applies to certain redemptions (e.g. travel through Chase's travel portal).

Perhaps you confused the 3 points per dollar the CSR earns on Travel/Dining expenses?

However, you are correct that points from other Chase cards can be moved to the CSR, and benefit from this 1.5x redemption.